# Why does an SVG background-image behave like background-size: contain? How do I stretch it?

Tags: html, css, svg

When using `background-size: 100% 100%`, the background image is supposed to be stretched to fit the background, without regard to aspect ratio. However, when the background-image is an SVG, browsers seem to treat it as `background-size: contain`, respecting the aspect ratio of the SVG. See this demo:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.bg.svg {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg);
}
.bg.png {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/PNG_demo_Banana.png);
}
```

```html
<p>Example SVG; behaves as if <code>background-size: contain</code>:</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg svg"></div>
</div>
<p>Example PNG; behaves correctly:</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg png"></div>
</div>
```

Above, the PNG (bottom image) behaves correctly: the image is stretched to fit the background. But the SVG (top image) behaves incorrectly: it is as if `background-size: contain` is set, rather than `background-size: 100% 100%`.

**How do I set an SVG background image to `background-size: 100% 100%`, stretching it to fit the background?**

Comment: @Dai the bottom one is a PNG, for comparison - it's stretched for me too, which is expected/correct. It's the top one that's a mystery ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think you've cracked it. Setting `preserveAspectRatio="none"` does exactly what I want. If you add this as an answer, I'd accept it.